# It is possible to intercept Response.Write with own code in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project I have a lot of handlers, each of it has hundreds of functions.

```
public class DataHandler1 : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
            switch (CommandName)
            {
                case "GetTime":
                    GetTime(context);
                    break;
                ....
            }
    }

    private void GetTime(HttpContext context)
    {
        string str = ...;
        context.Response.Write(str);
    }
```

Each function reads the `Request.QueryString` and writes result as `Response.Write`.

[image: example of handler functions]

Initially idea of this handlers was be call it only from JS, but now I need perform this handlers from server side (ASP.NET Classic). It's impossible to rewrite huge amount of functions or create double of this code for server side perform.

So, the best solution looks like an overload and override of `Response.Write` to receive simple string in my own code something in this way.

```
var X = new DataHandler1(context, myCurrentUserDM);
string ResponseWriteResult = X.GetTime.RequestQueryString("?a=1&b=2&c=3");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Those methods are `void`, so yhow you want to intercept it? I don't understand why a method `GetTime` is `void` and writes to the HttpContext itself. Why it's not only responsible to resolve the time and return it nnd let the caller decide what to do with it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, of course this function is void, but real return of this function is Response.Write. And I need a wrapper what return me Response.Write as result of function. But I can not understand how to do override existing Response.Write function.